# Get top 50 posts from reddit

Tags: json, api, reddit

I need to get  the top 50 entries from reddit link

Here is link

[Link](http://www.reddit.com/top)

I understood how to get posts , here is link to json

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/top.json
```

But how I can get top 50 posts?

Thank's for help.

Comment: Seems I understood how to do this

It's like this `https://www.reddit.com/top/.json?count=50`

Comment: nice catch. share your work at https://reddit.com/r/redditscripting

Comment: Oops, just saw that you already found the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick, other parameters can also be added to the end.

`http://reddit.com/r/redditdev.json?limit=50`